# Is there a way to restrict the Google Places Autocomplete to search a city's streets?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Can I restrict the search to a city's streets when using the Google Places `Autocomplete`?

Comment: By appending city name to the address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `Autocomplete` options to use `geocode` as the type, which will restrict the results that are returned to addresses:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'searchTextField' );
var options = {
  bounds: yourBounds,
  types: ['geocode']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
```

There is no way to restrict the results to *just* streets, but this will largely achieve what you want. If you set `yourBounds` correctly, maybe limited to the area of a city, it will get you as close as currently possible.

**Update responding to the comment:**

If you want to start by entering a city, you can bind the map's bounds to the `Autocomplete`s bounds, which will have the map set its viewport automatically when a city is selected in the `Autocomplete`:

```
var options = {
  bounds: yourBounds,
  types: ['(cities)']
};
autocomplete =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
// This will bind the map's bounds to the Autocomplete's bounds:
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

Then, you can update the `Autocomplete`'s  types, similar to the above, to have it return addresses:

```
autocomplete.setTypes( [ "geocode" ] );
```

From there, you can have a read of the [Places Library API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete).

Comment: Ok, but on Google Maps if I search 'New York' I get a map with the delimited city. Is not possible get those bounds?

Thanks for help

Comment: I've updated the content of my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you, it is that I want.

Comment: Good answer although I think the types option for cities should be ['(cities)'].

Comment: Yep, I forgot to include the parenthesis; I have updated the code sample to be correct. Thanks -

Answer (score 4):

Just an example of html code (twitter bootstrap 3 compatible :))

```
<div class="well container">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="locality" class="sr-only">Stadt oder PLZ</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locality" name="locality" placeholder="Stadt oder PLZ" />
          <p class="help-block">Bitte zuerst die Stadt oder PLZ eingeben.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="route" class="sr-only">Straße / Hausnummer</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-8" id="route" name="route" placeholder="Straße" disabled="true" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-4" id="street_number" name="street_number" placeholder="Nr." disabled="true" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I think the code is self-explanatory, just try it

```
<script>
var localityInput = document.getElementById('locality');
var localityOptions = {
  types: ['geocode'], //['(cities)'], geocode to allow postal_code if you only want to allow cities then change this attribute
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(localityInput, localityOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    $('#route').attr('disabled', false).focus();
    $('#street_number').attr('disabled', false);

    var boundsByCity = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.viewport;
    var routeInput = document.getElementById('route');
    var routeOptions = {
        bounds: boundsByCity,
        types: ['geocode']
    };
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(routeInput, routeOptions);
});
</script>
```

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8ncqjbeg/)

[Another demo more advanced](http://jsfiddle.net/emnafs74/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Set types to **regions**.

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'searchTextField' );

var options = {
  bounds: yourBounds,
  types: ['(regions)']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to restrict Places Autocomplete to `street_number` level but didn't find one.

The best solution I could come up with is to check for the `street_number` component in the places result and present a notification to the user if it was missing.

Example code:

```
var searchbox = document.getElementById('location');

var options = {             
    types: ['geocode']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchbox, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        var foundStreet = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var c = place.address_components[i];

            for (var j = 0; j < c.types.length; j++) 
            {
                if (c.types[j] == "street_number")
                {
                    foundStreet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (foundStreet)
                break;
        }

        if (!foundStreet)
            alert("Not a valid street number, add some pretty message to the user.");

        console.log(place);
    });
```