# free location service - street by name

Tags: java, javascript, geolocation

Does anyone knows any free location services that will allow me to find streets according to cities in Israel? I can use any java, .NET or javascript api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OSM Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is probably your best bet if you want to *search* for a street within a city.

The *nominatim.openstreetmap.org* servers have a somewhat restrictive [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy); [MapQuest also provides the Nominatim service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/) without usage limits.

If you're planning on a very high volume of queries, you'll be better off [installing Nominatim on your own servers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation), but be warned that this is ***not*** a trivial task, and the dataset is approaching a terabyte in size.

If you're looking for a *list* of streets, [there's a few options](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2980/how-do-i-list-all-the-streets-in-a-city-with-nominatim).  The easiest is to use [mapsomatic](http://maposmatic.org) to generate a CSV, but this is manual and only works if you need one or two cities.

[It's more complicated if you need more than one city:](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2980/how-do-i-list-all-the-streets-in-a-city-with-nominatim/3132)

> 1. download osmosis (and perhaps osmembrane which is a beta GUI for
>      osmosis)
> 2. download your country extract netherlands.osm.pbf (~430MB)
> 3. create a polygon file parseable by osmois (see osm2polygon)
> 4. run
>      osmosis with the polygon and extract all ways that have the tags
>      name=* and highway=residential
>
>    1. way-key name,highway
>    2. tag filter
>         reject-node, reject-relation

Comment: I saw Nominatim before but I cannot find how to get streets in a specific city using Nominatim?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any service to list all streets in a specific city.
Maybe you could use [The Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) and restrict places types to be streets (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653023/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-the-google-places-autocomplete-to-search-a-citys-str)).

Comment: If you familiar with google places autocomplete try to help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463286/google-places-api-find-an-address-using-the-city